# Load image from url, draw on its ImageBitmap and save as file on device in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to load an image from url into Jetpack Compose image and then I need to draw on it some lines, views. Then after editing it I need to save the file with my edited image on device storage. How can I draw on ImageBitmap in Jetpack Compose. Using AndroidView() doesn't suit me.

I expect that I will save edited image on device without using AndroidView().

Any ideas?

```
@Composable
fun LoadImageAndSave(
    imageUrl: String
) {
    var imageBitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader(context)

    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .target { result ->
            imageBitmap = result.current.toBitmap()
        }
        .build()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        LaunchedEffect(request) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                imageLoader.execute(request)
            }
        }

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            imageBitmap?.let {
                drawImage(it.asImageBitmap())

                // Is not drawn after clicking save button, only image and I want to draw here anything on bitmap
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    radius = 40f,
                    center = Offset(50f, 50f)
                )
            }
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                imageBitmap?.let { saveImage(it) }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("Save Image")
        }
    }
}

private fun saveImage(finalBitmap: Bitmap) {
    val destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath
    val myDir = File("$destination/my_images")
    myDir.mkdirs()
    val fname = "Image-${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
    val file = File(myDir, fname)
    if (file.exists()) file.delete()
    try {
        val out = FileOutputStream(file)
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
        out.flush()
        out.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see some code that you've tried.

Comment: Where is `saveImage`?

Comment: @CoolMind I updated my code